# monolog slackhandler and base file handler don't work together

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I tried so much.

```
 $monolog = Log::getLogger();

        $slackHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\SlackHandler(env("LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL"), 'translive', null, true, null, \Monolog\Logger::INFO, true, false ,false);
        $monolog->pushHandler($slackHandler);

        $dailyHandlerInfo = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path("logs/daily/info/info.log"), 0, \Monolog\Logger::INFO, false, 0664);
        $monolog->pushHandler($dailyHandlerInfo);



        $dailyHandlerError = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path("logs/daily/error/error.log"), 0, \Monolog\Logger::ERROR, false, 0664);
        $monolog->pushHandler($dailyHandlerError);

        $dailyHandlerCritical = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path("logs/daily/critical/critical.log"), 0, \Monolog\Logger::CRITICAL, false, 0664);
        $monolog->pushHandler($dailyHandlerCritical);
```

This is what I have in my laravel's provider's register method.

Error is: if I use only slackHandler, it works and sends log to slack. If I use RotatingFIleHandler 3 times as you see(info,error, critical have different pathes) , they work, but the problem is when I write like this (4 of them) , log don't go to slack at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `$bubble` argument passed when initializing the `RotatingFileHandler` is set to `false`.

This means that when it handles records, it'll not propagate them anymore. <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/6bb347c040bb29f42c2c249714aac8c0e36c2454/doc/01-usage.md#core-concepts)</sup>

Set `$bubble` to `true` if you'll like records handled in the RotatingFileHandler to be propagated on to the next log handler.

```
$dailyHandlerInfo = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(
    storage_path("logs/daily/info/info.log"), 0, \Monolog\Logger::INFO, true, 0664);
$monolog->pushHandler($dailyHandlerInfo);
```

**Update**

With regards to your comment about your intent setting `$bubble` to `false` in the `RotatingFileHandler`.

You can still go about maintaining the separation for between handlers and have them log to messages with different severity to separate files by being careful in the order the handlers are registered.

Register the `SlackHandler` and the top of the stack (*i.e.* let it come later after registering the `RotatingFileHandler`).

This way it is called first to handle the record before the others are called.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew that, but if I set it to true, then when I fire \Log::error("error message") , it prints this message in my info.log file and also in my error.log file. What i want is log::info should print message in my /info.log file only and log:error should print message in my error.log file even though its hierarchy is higher than info(Error>Info so it prints this message everywhere whose level is below it, but i don't want that.)

Comment: I see. You can keep the separation for records in separate files by registering the SlackHandler last. Note that handlers are invoked last in first out. See the updated section in my answer.

Comment: So what you say is first register RotatingFileHandler 3 times with different file pathes and $buble set to true and after these 3 registering, I should register slackHandler with buble with true?

Comment: Register like you do in your question with `$bubble` set to `false` and register `SlackHandler` last.

Comment: I also use laravel and I wanted not to register slackhandler at all, because I'd have it in logging.php file. like this - 'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['slack', 'daily']
        ],

Comment: The bad thing is what really happens is if I use laravel's logging.php file to put slack there, it goes to the list as the first, and then I register my own ones. so when I log, my own ones have buble false and they no longer give it to slack handler. do you understand how tricky it is?

Comment: If you're using laravel's logging configuration file, have `'slack'` as the last `Monolog` driver in the `channels` array configured for the `stack` driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185735/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-oluwafemi-sule).

Comment: It won't work like that because whatever code I posted here gets written in AppServiceProvider and I guess it gets executed after laravel's logging's array gets executed. that's why it doesn't work.